# Can I use ASP.NET Web API model binding for external services?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

If I want to make a call to here: 
http://thegamesdb.net/api/GetGamesList.php?name=x-men

I have the following two classes and I'm currently using `XMLDocument` to parse my respone:

```
        public class Data
        {
           private IEnumerable<Game> Game { get; set; } 
        }

        public class Game
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string GameTitle { get; set; }
            public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
            public string Platform { get; set; }
        }
```

I there a was I can streamline things by using ASP.NET Web API to make the call, and have it auto bind to my models? Or does this only work for sending out data from an `ApiController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just install the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client package - http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/4.0.20710.0

Now you can call the external service and read directly into your objects:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync("http://thegamesdb.net/api/GetGamesList.php?name=x-men");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var data = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Data>();
    foreach (var game in data.Game)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1};\t{2}", game.Id, game.GameTitle, game.Platform);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Given that the XML has a non-standard format for a collection, do it like this:

```
[XmlRoot("Data")]
public class Data
{
    [XmlElement("Game")]
    public List<Game> Games { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("Game")]
public class Game
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string GameTitle { get; set; }
    public string ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Platform { get; set; }
}
```

And:

```
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync("http://thegamesdb.net/api/GetGamesList.php?name=x-men");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var games = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Data>(new HashSet<MediaTypeFormatter>() { new XmlMediaTypeFormatter {UseXmlSerializer = true} });
        foreach (var game in games.Games)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1};\t{2}", game.id, game.GameTitle, game.Platform);
        }
    }
```

We need to hint the `XmlSerializer` how to treat the array which really is sent to you in the form of properties. Also, their date is not valid so you should save it to string (or parse in the setter).

Also, since we use `XmlSerializer` not `DataContractSerializer`, you can't use `IEnumerable`, it needs to be `List<T>`.

Comment: I set up a console app to test this code and I get this error: Error in line 1 position 7. Expecting element 'Data' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ConsoleApplication1'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'Data', namespace ''.

Comment: 1. you should decorate your class with [DataContract(Namespace = "")] and each property with [DataMember]. 2. I just looked at your XML and it will not deserialize into IEnumerable anyway, since <Game> is not an array, they are properties of <Data>. So you can't project that 1-to-1 to CLR object